# I have enabled virtualization and disabled Hyper-V still Intel x86 Hmax hardware doesn't install

Tags: android, android-studio

I have enabled virtualization and disabled Hyper-V, still Intel x86 Hmax hardware doesn't install.

[image: HP LAPTOP]

Comment: Try not to shout. Explain your problem.

Comment: isn't it because your CPU is not Intel?

Comment: It says that `This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology`, which is **obviously** not supported by AMD CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your computer have AMD processor